# Why didn't Ra's break into the Pit before?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

If I understood the story correctly Ra's was spared the Pit but his wife took his place. Why didn't he break into the Pit to save her?

Comment: I don't think he knew what had happened, so that he wouldn't know to go to the pit or where it was

Comment: Maybe you would like to comment on my answer!

Comment: @Mistu4u I like to think over answers before I comment or mark them correct. Also I feel comments or marking an answer correct too quickly keeps others from contributing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ra did not know his family is in the particular pit until the time, his daughter Talia informed him. When he was exiled he thought only he is punished for the love with the daughter of the warlord.

> When the warlord found out...
>
> ...the mercenary was condemned to this pit
>
> But then he exiled him instead.
>
> The mercenary understood that it was
>   the daughter who had secured his release.
>
> But what he could not know
>   was the true price of his freedom
>
> She took his place in the pit.

So Ra was unaware of his wife's imprisonment in the pit. So there was no reason for him to come back. But later he found out what happened to his family by Talia after she escaped the pit. But as his wife was dead by then, there was no reason for him to come back except to take revenge from the prisoners for the barbarism they did to his family. This concept is clear from Talia's admittance to Batman.

> I climbed out of the pit.
>
> I found my father...
>
> ...and brought him back
>   to exact terrible vengeance.

Comment: It's Ra's, not Ra.